# Bootstrap pagination CI setting on $config

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

If I have pagination with bootstrap that I created manual like this :

```
 <div class="pagination pagination-centered">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Prev</a></li>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

How can I make it true using $['config'] on CI ?
I just created like this :

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination pagination-centered"><ul>';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div><!--pagination-->';
```

The result is not I expected. ANy help it so appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = false;
$config['last_link'] = false;
$config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
```

And Tutorial [Here](http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2015/04/php-codeigniter-pagination-twitter-bootstrap-styles.html)